# Campo TimeStamp o Date and Time

Tags: firebird

En una tabla donde haya un campo de tipo TimeStamp que se use para por ejemplo entre otras cosas conocer la suma de todos los registros de una fecha en particular es decir haciendo:

```
select sum(campo_valor) from tabla where cast(campo_fecha as date)='2016-06-15'
```

¿Es mejor usar dos campos uno Date y otro Time o cast sigue siendo la mejor opcion?.

Ya que he notado que mis consultas con cast no las puedo indexar (o tal vez estoy haciendo algo mal), he tratado con todas las combinaciones posible de los campos de dicha tabla y la unica forma de que mi consulta se indexe y sea mas rapida por mas de 1 segundo es usando algo asi:

```
select (sum(campo_valor) from tabla where campo_fecha>='2016-06-15 00:00:00' and campo_fecha<=2016-06-15 23:59:59
```

Roberto Garcia

Comment: Gracias por la correcion no vuelve a pasar

Answer (score 0):

La razón por la que la primera consulta no se va por indices, es porque se aplica una función a la columna que se compara con una constante, lo que convierte al where en NON-SARGABLE.

Es decir, aunque exista un índice en campo_fecha, al utilizar el cast, se obliga a recorrer todos los registros para aplicarles la función, por lo que el indice es ignorado.

Afortunadamente, la mayoria de wheres NON-SARGABLE se pueden convertir en SARGABLE, con una pequeña manipulación, a la cual llegaste en la segunda consulta, al quitar la función cast de la columna y manejar un rango de fechas horas, y es por razón que la segunda consulta si se va por índice.

Así, puedes seguir utilizando el tipo de dato timestamp para esta columna, utilizando la búsqueda de la segunda consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de la siguiente manera, para tener que pasar solo una vez la fecha:
**Le paso la fecha sin hora** y toma desde esa fecha, hasta la inmediatamente siguiente.

```
SELECT SUM(CAMPO_VALOR) FROM TABLA
WHERE
CAMPO_FECHA >= :FECHA AND
CAMPO_FECHA < :FECHA + 1
```